# Add new JDBC Driver to connect Mathematica to SQL database

Tags: java, sql, databases

I cannot open a SQLConnection to a SQL vectorwise database and I assume the JDBC driver is the problem. A JAR file was provided to me - the only info additionally provided to me was the java class: **com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver**

What would I have to do to add it to the JDBCDrivers that Mathematica can use?

Hope this is sufficient information - please let me know, if more information is required.

Thanks and regards
Patrick

Answer (score 9):

Finally found the answer on how to connect MM to Actian vectorwise via SQL :)

```
Needs["JLink`"]
AddToClassPath["C:\\Users\\Desktop\\iijdbc.jar"];
Needs["DatabaseLink`"];

OpenSQLConnection[
 JDBC["com.ingres.jdbc.IngresDriver", 
  "jdbc:ingres://HOST:VW7/DATABASE;user=xxx;password=yyy"]]
```

Feeling good!
Pat

Answer (score 4):

In the case where you want to use an *updated* driver in preference to an older one shipped with Mathematica, `AddToClassPath[ ...path..., Prepend -> True]`.

For instance to use xerial's up-to-date SQLite driver:

```
Needs["JLink`"]; Needs["DatabaseLink`"]; 
ReinstallJava[];
jdbcdriver = FindFile["my-path-to/sqlite-jdbc-3.32.3.2.jar"]
AddToClassPath[jdbcdriver, Prepend -> True];
```