# JDBC::error when connecting to MySQL database

Tags: sql, databaselink, databases, jdbc

I'm trying to connect to a MySQL database. I've seen quite a few different methods (some of which are conflicting and seem to be outdated) of connecting but haven't managed to get any to work so far.

The following code gives an error message:

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]

OpenSQLConnection[
 JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", "ip/database"], 
 "Version" -> 3.1, "Catalog" -> Automatic, "Description" -> None, 
 "autoReconnect" -> True, "Password" -> "xxxx", 
  "Properties" -> {"useSSL" -> "False"}, "ReadOnly" -> Automatic, 
 "RelativePath" -> False,
   "TransactionIsolationLevel" -> Automatic, 
  "UseConnectionPool" -> Automatic, "Username" -> "root", 
  "Timeout" -> 1000]

(* JDBC::error: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' *)
```

Any help/suggestions with this would be much appreciate, thanks in advance!

Comment: This code seems okay and it also works for me, connecting to my local MySQL server. What problem do you have? Is there an error message? Since you are using an IP which is not publicly accessible, you most likely have not configured your firewall properly. Can you connect to the server with some other tools? Is this server on your local machine?

Comment: @Domen i get the error message: JDBC::error: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

Comment: Great, I get the same error when trying to connect to your server. I haven't been able to connect to your server with any other tools either, so the problem – as I have already stated – is not in Mathematica code but in the configuration of your server. If you answer to my other questions in the previous comment, we might be able to help you (although Mathematica SE is not really the right place for this kind of problems :)).

Comment: @Domen Thanks for getting back. Yes the server is on my local machine. I'm not sure about connecting to server with other tools, any suggestions?

Comment: If the server is on your local machine, then you shouldn't use your public IP, but ``localhost`` or ``127.0.0.1`` instead. That is: ``OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", "127.0.0.1/database"], ...]]`` Please let us know if this works.

Comment: Tried with this code:OpenSQLConnection[JDBC["MySQL(Connector/J)", "127.0.0.1/will"], 
 "Version" -> 3.1, "Catalog" -> Automatic, "Description" -> None, 
 "autoReconnect" -> True, "Password" -> "abcd", 
  "Properties" -> {"useSSL" -> "False"}, "ReadOnly" -> Automatic, 
 "RelativePath" -> False,
   "TransactionIsolationLevel" -> Automatic, 
  "UseConnectionPool" -> Automatic, "Username" -> "root", 
  "Timeout" -> 1000]. And still getting error

Comment: This error now: JDBC::error: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.

Comment: It seems like Mathematica uses an older version of JDBCDriver that doesn't support some default configuration of newer MySQL servers. Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50433762) to change settings on server.

Comment: @Domen it's now working, thanks so much for your help! Don't think I would have figured this out without it

Comment: Great! I have slightly changed your question so that it fits to this StackExchange. For any future questions: To avoid any security threats, do not post your IP and login details to public forums.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL provides two authentication plugins for user passwords: `sha256_password` and `caching_sha2_password`. In MySQL 8.0, `caching_sha2_password` is the default authentication plugin rather than `mysql_native_password`. However, the JDBC driver that is used in Mathematica to connect to a server implemented `caching_sha2_password` in version 5.1.46, as described in [changelog for MySQL Connector/J](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/connector-j-5.1-relnotes-en/news-5-1-46.html).

However, even in the latest Mathematica version 13.1.0, the included JDBC driver seems to be outdated (5.1.44).

```
Needs["DatabaseLink`"]
JDBCDrivers["MySQL(Connector/J)"]

(* JDBCDriver["Name" -> "MySQL(Connector/J)", 
 "Driver" -> "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", 
 "Protocol" -> {"jdbc:mysql://", "jdbc:mysql:loadbalance://"}, 
 "Version" -> 3.1, 
 "Description" -> "MySQL using Connector/J - Version 5.1.44", 
 "Location" -> "..."] *)
```

#### Solution A

Manually [download the newest JDBC driver](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/8.0.html). Then add it to Mathematica as described in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20365/add-new-jdbc-driver-to-connect-mathematica-to-sql-database).

#### Solution B

Change the authentication method in your MySQL server as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50433762).